# Python shares the default list param across instances

Tags: python

Why defining a default list for a class method's parameter makes it shared across instances?

Does that mean that this list param, *in the following example it is `props`*, got declared as a `class attribute` instead of an `instance attribute`?

And if so, does that mean that all the class method's params got defined as `class attributes`? and if so, why setting the name by appending a text string does not produce the same issue?

---

### Example

Given the following example

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name="", props=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.props = props

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name:<10} : props [{self._joined_props()}]"

    def AddProp(self, ptext):
        self.props.append(ptext)

    def AppendName(self, nodename):
        self.name += nodename

    def _joined_props(self):
        return ", ".join(self.props) 

node1 = Node()
node1.AppendName("node1")
node1.AddProp("p1")

node2 = Node()
node2.AppendName("node2")
node2.AddProp("p2")

print(node1)
print(node2)
```

outputs

```
node1      : props [p1, p2]
node2      : props [p1, p2]
```

Changing the `__init__()` to be

```
    def __init__(self, name="", props=[]):
        self.name = name
        # self.props = props # old
        self.props = []      # new
```

outputs the expected result

```
node1      : props [p1]
node2      : props [p2]
```

For a more realistic example, follow the `Node` class in the tree data structure demo defined @ [weshouman\tut-py-tree:tree.py#L61](https://github.com/weshouman/tut-py-tree/blob/5a5d327666e9e690fa51a53f0780cf10a7a644cc/tree.py#L61)

Comment: "Why defining a default list for a class method's parameter makes it shared across instances?" Defining a mutable argument in _any_ parameter list makes it shared across invocations of the function. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#what-actually-happens